# In "The Incredible Adventures of Van Helsing" how many auras/tricks can you learn?

Tags: adventures-of-van-helsing

There is room for 8 auras and 8 tricks, but i want to ask, if i fill all the slots and then want to learn a new one, can i override one that is already learned?

Comment: I remember at some point you get the option to respec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can, but for a price. 
The Romany encampment (in your private lab) has a male NPC to respec your abilities.

Be careful though, **each point you "remove" will cost you money!**